# How to display in a project that is called from another pipeline project in jenkins text in "Edit Build Information"

Tags: selenium, jenkins, pipeline

Hello: I have a pipeline project at Jenkins called "ProjectLaunch" that launches other projects automatically one day a week. I would like to show in "Edit Build Information" a text that says something like "ProjectCalled full launched", in the project that is called. With the pipeline I have in "ProjectLaunch" I can only get that text in its "Edit Execution Information" but not in the projects called.

My pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
                                
        stage('Proyect called') {                                   
            steps{                       
                build job: 'Proyect called',string(name: "DESCRIPTION", value: "ProjectCalled full launched") ]
            }                  
        }   
                      
    }
}
```

In the project called in the configuration I have an Execute system Groovy script, it is this:

```
import hudson.model.*
def build = manager.build
def params = build.action(hudson.model.ParametersAction).getParameters()
def description = "${params.DESCRIPTION}"
echo "Setting build description to: ${description}"
build.createSummary("Build description").appendText(description, "html")
```

But when I launch it I get this error:
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: manager for class: hudson1130775177255181016
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: manager for class: hudson1130775177255181016

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done the following because with Groovy I couldn't do it. I installed "Build Name and Description Setter" plugin. In the "ProjectLaunch" pipeline project, the pipeline would be more or less like this:

```
Pipeline {
agent any
parameters{
    
    string(name: "DESCRIPTION", defaultValue: "ProjectCalled full launched", description: "")
}
stages {
                                
    stage('ProjectCalled') {                                    
        steps{                       
            build job: 'ProjectCalled', parameters: [string(name: "DESCRIPTION", value: params.DESCRIPTION)]                    
        }                  
    }   
                  
}
```

}

And in the ProjectCalled in settings, add a parameter, I select the plugin option Changes build description, and I write ${DESCRIPTION}.

[Changes build description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBevp.png)

Ah!, I have also created string parameter named DESCRIPTION and without value.
[String parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qM5je.png)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't set the build description of a downstream job from an upstream Job. Hence in your Downstream Job, you can have some logic to set the description based on the trigger.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo 'Your second Job'
                    if(currentBuild.getBuildCauses()[0]._class == "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.BuildUpstreamCause") {
                        echo "This is triggered by  upstream Job"
                        currentBuild.description = "ProjectCalled full launched."
                    }

                }   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The called project is not a pipeline project, it is a project that launches selenium tests. In what part of the configuration should I write the code you have given me? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @sergio Assuming you are on a freestyle project, you can try using this plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/groovy/

Comment: I installed Groovy as recommended. But I'm not sure how to receive a parameter in the child project when the parent project starts, which in turn labels the execution. I edited the code in the initial question to make it clearer what I'm trying to do. Thank you